# Textbox validation in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am validating the text box value on following conditions

1. It should be minimum of 3 characters
2. It should contain only alphabets
3. It should contain at least one vowel

If all the conditions get matches I am enabling the submit button. 
If any of the above case are not matched I am setting an error message to div named error.

Here is my code

```
$document.ready(function(){

 $('.tbox').focus(); // cursor in text box 
 $(':submit').attr("disabled",true); // disable generate button

    $('.tbox').focus(fucntion(){

        check_the_input()   
    }); 


    });

function check_the_input()
{

    var value = $(this).val();

    $('.tbox').bind('keyup blur',function(){ 
    $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/[^a-z]/g,'') ); }

    if(value.length > 3)
    {
        if(value.indexOf('a') == -1 && value.indexOf('e') == -1 && value.indexOf('i') == -1 && value.indexOf('o') == -1 && value.indexOf('u') == -1)
        {
            $('#error').text("*Input must contain atleast one vowel");
            $(':submit').attr("disabled",true); 

        }
        else
        {
            $(':submit').attr("disabled",false);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        $('#error').text("*Input should be atleast 3 characters")
        $(':submit').attr("disabled",true); 
    }


    setTimeout(check_the_input,100);
}
```

I am facing following issues here:

1. If I type input as aa99 the input changes to aa , but still the generated button is enabled.
2. I am not getting the error at the time I type the text. Only after pressing tab or clicking mouse outside the textbox I am getting error.

Comment: Instead of 5 `indexOf` you can just do `if (!/[aeiou]/i.test(value)) {`

Comment: $('.tbox').focus(fucntion(){ <- you have a typo (fuNCtion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest rethinking the approach. Consider this simpler example:

**HTML:**

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="myinput"/>
  <button id="submit" type="submit" disabled>Submit</button>
  <p class="error"></p>
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

By using a function `test` and an object to store your validation filters your code becomes more obvious, more elegant and you get better performance and it's easier to maintain for example to add new filters or more inputs.

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/ezatap/6/edit

```
var $input = $('#myinput');
var $error = $('.error');
var $submit = $('#submit');
var Filters = {
  min: {
    re: /.{3,}/,
    error: 'Must be at least 3 characters.'
  },
  char: {
    re: /^[a-z]+$/i,
    error: 'Must be only letters.'
  },
  vowel: {
    re: /[aeiou]/i,
    error: 'Must have at least one vowel.'
  }
};

function test(value, filters) {
  var isValid = false;
  for (var i in filters) {
    isValid = filters[i].re.test(value);
    $error.hide();
    $submit.prop('disabled', false);
    if (!isValid) {
      $error.show().text(filters[i].error);
      $submit.prop('disabled', true);
      break;
    }
  }
  return isValid;
}

test($input.val(), Filters);
$input.on('keyup blur', function() {
  test(this.value, Filters);
});
```

Comment: marvellous.. thank you very much.. i think i have to learn filters.. will work on it..

Comment: Sure, check out http://elclanrs.github.com/jq-idealforms/, that's where most of this ideas come from.

Answer (score 1):

To the first question:

```
else
{
    $('#error').text("*Input should be atleast 3 characters")
}
```

=>

```
else
{
    $('#error').text("*Input should be atleast 3 characters");
    $(':submit').attr("disabled",true); 
}
```

To the second question:

When the input is being edited, no callback will be called until the input lost its focus.
If you would like to change the style of the :submit when editing, you can setup a periodically called function that checks the input every few milliseconds. here's a simple example:

```
function check_the_input( )
{
   //routines check the input
   //...

   setTimeout( check_the_input, 100 ); //call me after 0.1 second
}

$(document).ready( function( ) { check_the_input( ) } );
```

of course there's more work to do if you want higher efficiency.

fix several error, see this: http://jsfiddle.net/4E7vv/2/

Comment: yeah, thank you. I have updated the code. But still i face the same problem. If the input is aaa99 the generate button gets disabled and only after pressing key the input is getting validated .

Comment: sorry.. Noting worked out. Can you help me out.. I ve updated the code

Comment: @srinath, it is not `fucntion`, but `function`, you've made a typo